Incorrect Translation Results with ImageRegistrator in Kornia
I'm encountering an issue with the ImageRegistrator in Kornia while trying to register two frames using translation. The function consistently returns incorrect translation values, even for a basic synthetic test case. Below is the code I used to test the translation registration. Could someone please guide me on the correct approach?

Reproduction steps
import numpy as np
import torch
import kornia as K
import kornia.geometry as KG
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import Tuple

def find_frame_translation_kornia(frame_1: np.ndarray, frame_2: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[Tuple[float, float], np.ndarray, bool]:
    """Find translation between two frames using Kornia's ImageRegistrator."""
    
    frame_1 = K.image_to_tensor(frame_1, False).float() / 255.0  # Shape: (C, H, W)
    frame_2 = K.image_to_tensor(frame_2, False).float() / 255.0  # Shape: (C, H, W)
    
    if frame_1.ndim == 3:
        frame_1 = frame_1.unsqueeze(0)  # Shape: (1, C, H, W)
    if frame_2.ndim == 3:
        frame_2 = frame_2.unsqueeze(0)  # Shape: (1, C, H, W)

    registrator = KG.ImageRegistrator("translation") # same results for "similarity", "homography", etc.

    try:
        model = registrator.register(frame_1, frame_2)
        tx, ty = model[0, :2, 2].cpu().detach().numpy()

        shift = (tx, ty)
        M = np.array([[1, 0, tx], [0, 1, ty]], dtype=np.float32)

        success = True

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Registration failed: {e}")
        shift, M, success = (0, 0), np.eye(3, dtype=np.float32)[:2, :], False

    return shift, M, success

def create_translated_image(image: np.ndarray, tx: int, ty: int) -> np.ndarray:
    rows, cols = image.shape
    M = np.float32([[1, 0, tx], [0, 1, ty]])
    translated_image = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (cols, rows))
    return translated_image

def test_find_frame_translation_kornia():
    image = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
    image[30:70, 30:70] = 255  # A white square in the center

    tx, ty = 5, -3
    translated_image = create_translated_image(image, tx, ty)

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    plt.title("Original Image")
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(translated_image, cmap='gray')
    plt.title("Translated Image")
    plt.show()

    shift, M, success = find_frame_translation_kornia(image, translated_image)

    assert success, "Registration failed"
    np.testing.assert_almost_equal(shift, (tx, ty), decimal=1)
    expected_M = np.array([[1, 0, tx], [0, 1, ty]], dtype=np.float32)
    np.testing.assert_almost_equal(M, expected_M, decimal=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_find_frame_translation_kornia()

Issue:
When running the test, the function returns significantly incorrect translation values. Specifically, for a known translation of (5, -3), the function returns (-0.1, 0.1). Here is the error message I received:
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 1 decimals

Mismatched elements: 2 / 2 (100%)
Max absolute difference: 5.09875337
Max relative difference: 1.02040539
 x: array([-0.1,  0.1], dtype=float32)
 y: array([ 5, -3])

Expected behavior
The function should correctly identify the translation (5, -3) between the original and translated images.
Environment

PyTorch Version (e.g., 1.0): 2.4.0+cpu
OS (e.g., Linux): Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
How you installed PyTorch (conda, pip, source):
[pip3] torch-pitch-shift==1.2.4
[pip3] torchaudio==2.3.0
[pip3] torchmetrics==1.4.0.post0
[conda] numpy                     1.26.4                   pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torch                     2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
Build command you used (if compiling from source):
Python version: 3.9.19
CUDA/cuDNN version: False
GPU models and configuration: False
Any other relevant information:


